# VBA code for moving a row based on criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to StackExchange and VBA and I have tried to find an answer to this but I'm having issues!!!

I have a spreadsheet where information is input and appears in Sheet 2, columns B-I. What I would like it to do is that if Column H is blank, it moves the whole row into column L to S. So my data will be split into 2 separate places on the same sheet based on whether H is empty or populated.

The information in column H will be different every time so i can't specify what will be in the column, but there are times when there will be nothing input into column H and that is when I want it to move.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?
Many thanks
Bev

Comment: the whole column `H` or just for the rows having nothing in column `H`?

Comment: If the row has nothing in column H I want that row to move, if there is something in column H I want the row to stay.

Comment: So what happened with this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this for a starting point

```
Option Explicit
Const FIRST_ROW As Long = 2
Const LAST_ROW As Long = 100
Const FIRST_SOURCE_COL As Long = 2 'column B
Const LAST_SOURCE_COL As Long = 9 'column I
Const TRIG_COL As Long = 8 'column H
Const GAP As Long = 2 'columns gap between original data and moved data

Sub moveit()
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long
Const DIST As Long = LAST_SOURCE_COL - FIRST_SOURCE_COL + GAP + 1

For r = FIRST_ROW To LAST_ROW
    'check if we need to move
    If Cells(r, TRIG_COL).Value = "" Then
    'move the data
        For c = FIRST_SOURCE_COL To LAST_SOURCE_COL
            Cells(r, c + DIST).Value = Cells(r, c).Value
            Cells(r, c).Value = ""
        Next
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks... That works good to separate it and put it on another page, but I also need it to disappear from the original page if that is possible?

Comment: it is moving it to a new page rather than a different place on the same page too.

Answer (score 1):

Move the blanks,

```
Sub MoveBlanks()
    Dim lRws As Long, sh As Worksheet, x

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet2")

    With sh
        lRws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        For x = lRws To 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(x, "H") = "" Then
                .Range(.Cells(x, "B"), .Cells(x, "I")).Cut .Cells(.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .Range(.Cells(x, "B"), .Cells(x, "I")).Delete Shift:=xlUp
            End If
        Next x
    End With

End Sub
```

**Before**

[image]

**After**
[image]

Comment: Move Blanks doesn't seem to do anything... sorry

Comment: Column H , Row 23 is blank - I am looking at it now... 1-22 are populated, but nothing is moving over....

Comment: Yes, Column B will always be populated, its Column H that could be blank - thats the one I want it to check before it moves the full row over..  if that makes sense (I'm just learning!!!)

Comment: I can't see a picture sorry! all i see is the word Before then the word After

Comment: [Before](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ni5f6.jpg) and [After](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8iyjO.jpg)...maybe this will work

Comment: still nothing just a blank page! - possibly my permissions at work won't allow it?

Comment: Yes it does match exactly. Don't understand why its not working. Nothing happens at all!

Comment: lets see a screen shot